# how to set administrator menu

Tags: navigation, routes

i want to set

```
Site building
Site data management
Site configuration
Site users management
Store administration
Reports
```

as menus as admin login, else it show other menu bar.

```
Home
Search
Mark List
Contact
Help
```

so can any one suggest how will I achieve this.
cheers.
Sanjay Dev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you are using Drupal 6. The [Admin menu](http://drupal.org/project/admin_menu) module provides a nice menu on top of the page for all admin items the user has access to.

[Screen shot of admin menu http://drupal.org/files/images/Administration-menu.preview.png](http://drupal.org/files/images/Administration-menu.preview.png)

Comment: it is only for admin I want to make it role-wise. for specific role specific menu should be available. can i configure it more for this type of menues....